# Can't login to openshift origin?

Tags: azure, redhat, openshift-origin

I installed openshift origin in CentOS 6.5 minimal installation on Windows Azure vps using oo-installer. I used same server as both broker and node. Installation completed without any errors. After installations when I tried to login to the openshift console using username/password as openshift/openshift and admin/admin but it is giving an error stating as bad password. I tried to connect to the server using `rhc` but same results occurred. Now where can I change my password? Where will be the openshift's log files? How can I diagnose my openshift installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default credentials are 'demo/changeme', according to [this guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_puppet.html). They worked for my Origin install.

You can change the password and add users with htpasswd (check out [this post](http://mfojtik.im/openshift-on-digitalocean)). So, for example:

```
sudo yum install -y htpasswd
htpasswd -c /etc/openshift/htpasswd demo
```

A lot of the relevant log files were in **/var/log/openshift** for me.

I found the command `oo-diagnostics -v –abortok` useful for diagnosing issues.

Hope that helps!

Comment: where you got 'oo-diagnostics' script? link to it in documentation is broken 

http://openshift.github.io/documentation-latest/oo_troubleshooting_guide.html